# What is the earliest instance of a SciFi work describing a massive universal database of knowledge?

Tags: technology, history-of, computers

What is the earliest instance of a SciFi work describing a system satisfying the following criteria (basically a massive computer database coupled with the networking system to access it available to everyone)?

- Database contains 100% of available knowledge (or as practically close to it as possible), necessarily including but not limited to:

  - scientific information
  - personal data
  - news/events
- All of that information can be queried out, possibly with some controls to satisfy privacy needs.
- Universal access (e.g. practically any person on Earth can connect as a person, not just select few or limited by profession/organization). This one trips up many possibilities, e.g. H2G2 which arguably might fit the other criteria.

The precise implementation doesn't matter, some supercomputer, a super-AI, a whole planet ala H2G2 or a who-knows-how-it-works black box - doesn't matter. But it must satisfy the rules above.

The earliest one I can think of is from 1978, but it's in Russian (for those who care but can't guess, "BVI" - Big World Informatory - from Strugatsky brothers).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mark Twain's short story, [*From The 'London Times' of 1904*](http://www.readbookonline.net/readOnLine/998/), from 1898 is often regarded as the first writing that describes a world-wide communications network for information sharing although I'm not sure if it fits your requirement for a database. While it does mention a level of interactivity and such that would probably require a database of some sort it doesn't explicitly state it outright.

[*The Machine Stops*](http://www.plexus.org/forster/index.html) by E. M. Forster, published in 1909 might fit your requirements better. It's about the dystopian world that develops when a machine that's controlling everything and facilitates the endless discussion of secondhand ideas (sound familiar?) breaks down.  Read it and see what you think.

Comment: I was about to suggest *The Machine Stops*.

Answer (score 7):

I think most of the [Multivac stories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivac) written by Asimov are some of the earliest examples of this.  Namely, [The Last Question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Question) which contains, especially near the end, a galaxy spanning super computer that anyone in the human race can access.  The earliest of these stories were written in the mid 1950s.

Answer (score 6):

**[Paris in the Twentieth Century](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_in_the_Twentieth_Century)** (French: Paris au XXe siècle) is a science fiction novel **by [Jules Verne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Verne)**, **written in 1863** but first published in 1994, where a worldwide "telegraphic" communications network is mentioned, **a possible premonition of the Internet**, that I think satisfy the rules above.

Answer (score 6):

The oldest version of this idea that I know of is not strictly science fiction; it's called the Akashic Records which is a Hindu belief dating back to at least the late 18th century that there is a record kept of all experiences by every living thing. The records can be accessed via near-death experiences or by achieving certain Astral mental states.

Like I said, not actually sci-fi but if you're looking for old I think the Akashic Records are your best bet.

Comment: Never heard of this before - but it's definitely a cool idea.

Comment: Sounds sci fi to me! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akashic_records

Answer (score 1):

["The Life and Times of Multivac"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Life_and_Times_of_Multivac) (1975) is one of a series of short stories that describe a very big computer called [Multivac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivac), the computer is first mentioned in the short story [Question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_%28short_story%29) (1955).

Comment: It would be nice if you included the date of the story.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto I took some liberties in my edit...and added the date for him. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I am not sure if it qualifies for a book or not but Hindu mythology talks about a recordkeeping of all the good and  bad stuff that every human does based on which the person's after life "benefits"/Quality of life are decided..

Comment: Many religions do this (eg [Christianity](http://biblehub.com/revelation/20-12.htm)) but I suspect this Hindu story is the oldest. Can you add a date to this answer?

Comment: Although, I'm not sure Hindu mythology counts as a "sci-fi" work as requested in the question...

Comment: @Wikis - it isn't, according to site rules

Answer (score 0):

Ernst Jünger's Eumeswil (1977) (see [German wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eumeswil) for more detail - [English wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eumeswil) is quite short and omits discussion of the SF aspects) describes a sort of wikipedia like database of historical-only knowledge called the Luminar. The user can query it over things in the past which are then displayed on a monitor.

Comment: But the question is asking for the *earliest* instance, and other answers have already gone well earlier than the 1970s.